# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a set of urls,i have those urls in a list called list(eg `http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=s9_al_bw_brwse_a_v?_encoding=UTF8&node=9097393011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-4&pf_rd_r=10RXCP9TZPW3BP73EKHA&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1818119462&pf_rd_i=2858778011`). At the bottom of this urls page there is the number of pages for each category.

There is  a span element from which i am trying to return a url.But it is returning `NoneType error`

The code i have tried so far

```
for links in full_links:
    mech=Browser()
    mech.set_handle_robots(False)
    mech.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    url=links
    page=mech.open(url)
    html=page.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    no_pages = soup.find('div',id="pagn")
    a=no_pages.find('span',{'class':'pagnLink'})
    for aes in a:
        print aes.text
        for a in elm.findAll('a'):
            link='http://www.amazon.com'+a['href']
            print link
```

Comment: `soup=BeautifulSoup(html)no_pages = soup.find('div',id="pagn")` What are you trying to achieve with this line? Or are you missing a newline

Comment: @TimCastelijns Getting the contents inside div#pagn

Comment: When I run this code I don't get `NoneType error`, I get `SyntaxError` at `soup=BeautifulSoup(html)no_pages = soup.find('div',id="pagn")`. Please double check that this code is identical to the version you're running. (hint: I second Tim's "are you missing a newline?" question)

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra: what Tim meant is that that line was not legal Python. Since that would have thrown a *different* exception, I've separated the two expressions into two lines for you.

Answer (score 2):

You failed to include a full traceback, but presumably it is the `soup.find('div')` call that returned `None`. For *that page* the element you tried to find is *not* present.

If an element is not found, `Element.find()` returns `None`, and a subsequent line that tries to use that `None` value will fail. In this case `no_pages` is `None`, so `no_pages.find()` then fails.

For element searches like these, it is *much easier* to use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for page_link in soup.select('div#pagn span.pagnLink a[href]'):
    link = 'http://www.amazon.com' + page_link['href']
    print link
```

This will find all links within the `<div id="pagn">` -> `<span class="pagnLink>` element tree, provided they have an `href` attribute.

This search will just return an empty loop if either the `div` or the `span` is not present.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra: For the URL you have given in your post, there is one match. If you do not see anything for that URL, then it could be that you have an error in how you load the page or you have `lxml` installed but have a problem with the `libxml2` library (rarer these days) and the parse fails for some reason.